# Xamarin wrapper hell - handling lots of external dependencies

Tags: .net, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have one topic that gives me sleepless nights. It's Xamarin binding wrappers. I have a project which requires usage of external library.

On iOS side it's not so bad - just about 6 frameworks.
But talking about Android - we have somewhere around 10-15 jars an 6 aars. 
Most of them quite frequently updated.

Wrapping all of this is one terrible and horrible nightmare. How to handle it? Wrapper projects are nearly not reusable, there are tons of errors. Each update takes us sometimes 2-3 weeks of full team job to wrap it. And after that we have another 1-2 weeks to implement it because of reference problems.

There needs to be some simpler way. How do you handle your wrappers? Is there any possibility for some kind of merging jars/aars and frameworks to simplify this job?

Answer (score 0):

> There needs to be some simpler way. How do you handle your wrappers? Is there any possibility for some kind of merging jars/aars and frameworks to simplify this job?

You may refer to [Binding a Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/), it uses JNI to invoke calls in Java library code directly, create a `Bindings Library` that automatically wraps the library with C# wrappers so you can invoke Java code via C# calls.

For .Jar lib, please refer to [Binding a .JAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) and for .aar, check this doc: [Binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/).

Sometimes after creating a binding library, some errors will be shown when building this lib, then you may need to check [Customizing Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/) and [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/). Usually problems can be solved by modifying the metadata file or adding additional partial class/ interface... and then override it according to the original Java lib.

Comment: After making dozens of fully functional Binding Java Libraries for both Jar and AAR I can tell you - it's not working. There are hundreds of problems not solvable by metadata or adding partial classes/interfaces. Every new jar/aar requires new problem solving. Lots of cases requires even manual editing of obj generated files. So no. I'ts not a good way to handle dependencies.

And we are talking here only on Android. What about iOS? You have library, your developers update to new version of swift and tada, it's whole new world once again.

Comment: @PatrykRomańczuk, if there're problems cannot be solved, maybe you can directly post question asking about specific problem, it should be helpful for Xamarin to improve compatibility with Java lib. For iOS, I'm not familiar with it, but there is document about [Binding iOS Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/).

Comment: @PatrykRomańczuk, For the lib's update issue, yeah, it should be wrapped again, Xamarin is not the author of those libraries, it's lucky if we can find libs which have xamarin version and those versions should also be updated if original libs get updated, still it could be a new world again. You're right that it's too trouble to convert Java lib to C#, I also think so.

Comment: Right now I'm far from solving problems one by one. There are just too many, too oftem. The question is - when you know that you will have somewhere around 25 libraries to wrap and update on regular basies what can you do? Right now we are wrapping and implementing this libraries slower than they are coming and that's just insane.

Comment: @PatrykRomańczuk, sorry, I don't have better idea, AFAIK, there is no simpler way to wrapper. If you're asking for some tool like things to do this work, sorry, I don't know...